# Segmentation fault in c sscanf

Tags: c, variables, format, scanf

I'm new in programming. Could you tell me why does this code cause segmentation fault?
How should I declare variables a and b to use them further in sscanf?

```
   string f = "123.45678";
   string a = "aaa";
   string b = "aaaaaa";
   sscanf (f, "%[^.]%s",a ,b );
   printf ("%s and %s %s \n", a, b, f);
```

Comment: What is `string`? Off the top of my head, it looks like you're mixing C++ objects with C functions.

Comment: `"aaa"` and `"aaaaaa"` are read-only `const char*` strings. Try `char a[4] = "aaa";` and `char b[7] = "aaaaaa";`, and then think about what will happen when the user enters strings that are too large to be stored in these arrays.

Comment: This code really compile without warning ?

Comment: `C++` compiler?

Comment: Please read about and include in your question a [MCVE]. There is no `string` type in C; perhaps the [tag:cs50] header was included?

Comment: C compiler. string is char*

Comment: yes cs50 header was included.

Comment: the char *'s `a` and `b` are being initialized to point to items in read only memory.  Such items cannot be modified,

Comment: when using the input/conversion specifiers `[...]` and '%s`  always use a MAX CHARACTERS modifier that is 1 less than the length on the input buffer.  AND always check the returned value (not the parameter values) from the `scanf()` family of functions to assure the operation was successful.

Answer (score 0):

this statement:

```
sscanf (f, "%[^.]%s",a ,b );
```

is causing the seg fault event because the pointers `a` and `b` are pointed toward read only memory.   Suggest changing

```
string a = "aaa";
string b = "aaaaaa";
```

to be items on the stack via:

```
string a[4] = "aaa";
string b[7] = "aaaaaa";
```

Then, for safety, change:

```
sscanf (f, "%[^.]%s",a ,b );
```

to something similar to:

Note: It is unclear if you want the `.` to be the first character of `b`.  Place a `.` between the input format specifiers if do not want the `.` to be part of the second input

```
if( 2 != sscanf (f, "%3[^.].%6s", a ,b ) )
{
    perror( "sscanf failed" );
    exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
}

// implied else, sscanf successful
```

Comment: And how to do, if I don't know length of a or b in advance? What if I just want to split a string and store it's value in two strings? An array [2] maybe?

Comment: @LCK, you have the source string,  the code can use `strlen()` to get the length of the source string.  Then call  `malloc( strlen( f ) )` once for `a` and once for `b` .  BTW: `f` best be a buffer, not a file pointer, because the posted code is using `sscanf()` which extracts from a buffer, not from a file

Comment: Great! Thanks   user3629249